# Notification error while truing to compile a source code

Tags: unix, compilation

I am trying to compile a source code, the instructions tell me to first do a macros.inc with the

```
make config
```

option, before i start I checked what version i have

```
mpif90 -v --> mpif90 for MPICH2 version 1.2.1
```

So if i have understood correctly the compiler is loaded,

when i typed  the make config it gave me this error

```
pcw3738> make config
which: no ifort in (/home/george/bin/share:/home/george/bin/x86_64:/home/george/bin/share:/home/george/bin/x86_64:/home/george/bin/share:/home/george/bin/x86_64:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/NX/bin:/usr/local/share/bin:/usr/local/share/bin:/usr/local/share/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/openwin/bin)
```

How can i fix this to finish my installation?

thank you

Comment: Most likely that `ifort` command is called from within the "config" target defined inside your Makefile. I suggest you take a look into that Makefile to see the command. Next you should find out what that `ifort` thing is and how you can install it since it is obviously missing.

Comment: OR try this first; `./configure ; make ; make install` .... `make config` is not a standard build pattern (that I'm aware of). Good luck.

Comment: You may simply need to tell make to use `mpif90` as the fortran compiler rather than `ifort`.  If some standard conventions were followed, you may be able to simple do `FC=mpif90 make config`.  This is a shot in the dark.